# dynamically add / remove fields django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

How do I create a button to add and remove a fields, and then save some fields using django (2.0)?

my views.py

```
def add_preventivo(request):
if request.method == "POST":
        form = PreventivoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            preventivo = form.save(commit=False)
            preventivo.published_date = timezone.now()
            preventivo.save()

else:
    form = PreventivoForm()

return render(request, 'add_preventivo.html', {'form':form})
```

my models.py

```
class Preventivo(models.Model):
cliente = models.ForeignKey('Cliente',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
prestazione = models.ForeignKey('Prestazione',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
numero = models.IntegerField(default='1')
prezzo = models.IntegerField(default='0')
```

I must be able to repeat "prestazione" and "numero" and I must have a sum of the various repetitions on "prezzo"

Comment: _How do I create a button to add and remove_ Add and remove what?

Comment: Also, why are you setting string defaults on integer values?

Comment: @JohnGordon  a Field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is a many-to-one relationship between `Preventivo` and `prestazione`. That means one `prestazione` can be linked to many `Preventivo`s, but each `Preventivo` can only be linked to one `prestazione`.

If you want to be able to assign multiple `prestazione` objects to one `Preventivo`, you should implement a many-to-many relationship. See the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). You should consider using an [intermediary field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) to store the other information you need.